# Foreach in R does not work when a vectorized function calls another function

Tags: r, foreach, vectorization

If `foreach` calls a vectorized function `fvec`, which then calls a further function `g`, I get an error message saying that g can't be found.

This code

```
library(doParallel)
f <- function(x){
  x+g(x)
}
g <- function(x){
  x^2
}
fvec <- Vectorize(f)
registerDoParallel(cores=2)
foreach(i=1:5,.combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  fvec(i)
}
```

produces this error

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "g""
```

However, using `f` instead of `fvec` works, using `%do%` instead of `%dopar%` also works.

How do I get `%dopar%` to work properly in this instance. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't fix it. It's able to detect the `g` when using `f` instead of the vectorized version. Moving `fvec <- Vectorize(f)` inside the `foreach` seems to work though.